# No se porque mi formulario no toma mi etiqueta style, asi modifique cualquier atributo no lo toma

Tags: html, css

```
mi codigo
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="es"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <title>mensaje por wts</title> <style> .icon-wts{ width: 70px; height: 70px; position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 20px; } .form-wts{ width: 220px; height: 280px; background: skyblue; position: fixed; bottom: 80px; right: 50px; box-shadow: 0 2 px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22); border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; } .inputwts{ width: 100%; padding: 5px; color: ; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.19); } .inputwts: focus{ outline: none; } .textareawts{ width: 100%; padding: 5px; color: ; height: 120px; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.19); } .textareawts: focus{ outline: none; } </style> </head> <body> <div>
------------------------------------------------------------------------

      <form clas="form-wts" action="">
          <p>Nuevo Mensaje</p>
          <label for="">Nombre</label>
          <input class="inputwts"type="text" placeholder="Nombre"name="">
          <label for="">Mensaje</label>
          <textarea clas="textareawts"name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
          <button>Enviar Mensaje</button>
        
      </form>

          <img class="icon-wts" src="wts.png" alt="wts">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

***.form-wts, no toma ningún atributo que el he puesto, modifico cualquiera de ellos pero no lo toma cual es mi error ?***

Comment: en el form es "class" no "clas" como pusiste vos.

Comment: papi lo amo gracias <3

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por tu pregunta

Revisando el código que compartistes.

Debes corregir el nombre de la propiedad ***class*** en la etiqueta ***form***. Lo declarastes como ***clas***, y lo correcto seria ***class***

Tu código:

```
<form clas="form-wts" ...
```

Lo correcto

```
<form class="form-wts" ...
```

Prueba si con este cambio el script style de lee el estilo.

Saludes